# Web API (like github REST API) for a personal Git server repo to enable "git log"?

Tags: web-services, git, github, github-api, git-log

**I probably end up re-inventing parts of the [github REST API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) for my own repo server. But maybe there is some server script to do that already out there? Or maybe you have other suggestions?**

**This is my use case:**

I am developing a Firefox Extension, that shall display the data of a

```
git log -- <path>
```

I always could write a little server script that implements the well developed [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) and does the "git log" command there. But then, the FF extension depends on that server script ;(

I was wondering, if there exists something like the [github REST API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) for "not-github"-repos that would be more standard as my little server script?

I also thought about a [Git JS Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411302/javascript-git-client), like [Git.JS](https://github.com/danlucraft/git.js) (apparently the only JS Client; workes with node.js; Unfortunatly the project is no more active and has no documentation.) . However, I don't need a full client. I just want to retrieve some information Read Only from the remote master repo.

Comment: Is the repo local on the enduser's computer or on your server?

Comment: The repo should be on my server. Just like I would be github.com

Answer (score 5):

Although I am late to the party I have noticed a few a might contribute to the answer.

[Orion Git API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/Server_API/Git_API) Orion is an Eclipse project

[RESTFul Git](https://github.com/hulu/restfulgit) from Hulu on github

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't tried it, [GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/) is a VERY cool option. I have multiple installations on a few windows dedicated servers that I pull together using a REST API. I had it up and running in 5 minutes, in Windows, using the "GO: Single-Stack Solution".

> Gitblit GO is an integrated, single-stack solution based on Jetty.
>
> You do not need Apache httpd, Perl, Git, or Gitweb. Should you want to use some or all of those, you still can; Gitblit plays nice with the other kids on the block.
>
> This is what you should download if you want to go from zero to Git in less than 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you definitely need to implement some kind of server-side code by your own.

You can choose any server-side language you like. I believe `ruby` or `python` will work fine. Than create simple web-site with one page embedding output of `git log` according to the parameters given.

All other options will not work for you, I believe. You cannot remotely access git repository's history due to distributed nature of git — you can read history of your local repository only.

Reading that web-page by your extension and parsing output will give you what you need.