# How can I only upload deltas for version control to my server? Without forcing user to install any tools

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, git-svn, rsync

I want to make a website that lets users upload files onto the cloud based web server. But I don't want the users to upload the complete file every time they make a change. I know github achieves this by making users install git in windows. Also, I don't want to force the users to install git on their systems.

**How can I put a version control system as a drag and drop solution in my website?**

Lets say on my website, a user has a file `'x'(130kb)` already in his repo, and he makes changes to `'x'(now its 150kb)` in his system and drags and drops it into my website, how can I ensure that only 20kb, (not exactly 20kb, I mean just the changes), is uploaded onto my server.

Maybe something like a light weight git alternative in javascript?

Comment: [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)?

Comment: Can `rsync` be used in this context? I don't want to direct the user to install anything on their system. I want the solution to be completely via browser? Is there any client side web script to do it? If yes,Can you explain how i can use rsync?

Comment: It was just a thought. But no matter what, you always _will_ end up with something client side to figure out the delta - how is your server supposed to know which parts of the file to request without knowing the new file in advance?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Javascript Git client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411302/javascript-git-client). Also maybe interesting: http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/creationix/js-git, https://github.com/creationix/js-git

Comment: i was thinking may be when the user drags and drops the file, the javascript code queries the server for the same file name and then send some meta data regarding the file in the server and only the changes can be uploaded. I am not sure about all this. I am a beginner in web technologies.

Comment: I see, yes, it might be possible. But when you say you're a beginner, it's probably a pretty tough challenge. Maybe you can browse around on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ for an existing solution to this instead of trying to do it from scratch

Comment: Can you direct me on what kind of meta data should the server be sending back to the client. I am still unable to figure out any other possible way than sending the previous version of the whole file back to the client. Is there an alternative solution to this approach?

Comment: Check on rsync's protocol. But really, check webmasters.SE for already existing solutions before trying to craft a squared wheel...

Answer (score 1):

See also this google lib for diff/patch : [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053587/javascript-based-diff-utility) I found [jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) which I would suggest could act as the basis of a browser based diff and send the diff/patch tool.

A couple of cautions:

1. It is probably worth following the unified diff format so that standard patch tools can be used.
2. Binary files, especially zip files, often get a lot bigger when diff is taken so you will either need to Forbid binary files, test for binary files and upload those directly, check if the patch is bigger than the whole file or a combination of the forgoing.